# Perl forking then stopping multiple child processes from parent

Tags: perl, fork

In this scenario, I need my perl program to start multiple child processes that last an unknown amount of time, and in fact only the parent process knows when the child processes need to end. I've been trying to fork off more than one process then ending it from the parent but have been unsuccessful. What I have so far:

Successfully forking off one process then ending it

```
my $pid = fork();

if($pid == 0){
    #do things in child process
}

else{
    #examine external conditions, when the time is right:
    kill 1, $pid;
}
```

Unsuccessfully trying to extend it to 2 processes:

```
my $pid = fork();

if($pid != 0){ #parent makes another fork
    my $pid2 = fork();
}

if($pid == 0 || $pid2 = 0){
    #do things in child process
}

else{
    #examine external conditions, when the time is right:
    kill 1, $pid;
    kill 2, $pid;
}
```

I've read all the documentation on fork available on the internet, and it was all written about forking off one process which I understand pretty well, but I have no clue how to extend it to 2 or more processes, and would appreciate any help on how to do that.

Comment: *"I've read all the documentation on fork available on the internet"* that must have taken you months!

Comment: Why are you using two different signals? Signal 1 is SIGHUP (on Linux), and signal 2 is SIGINT, yet you should be using SIGTERM: `kill TERM => $pid;`

Comment: Borodin, haha, yes that was a bit of an exaggeration, would be more appropriate to say that I've read the top 10-15 relevant articles/man pages, and @ikegami, I meant to write kill 1, $pid2, my apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this code, I hope the code is self explanatory:

```
my $num_process = 5; ## for as many you want, I tested with 5
my %processes; ## to store the list of children

for ( 1 .. $num_process ) {

    my $pid = fork();

    if ( not defined $pid ) {
        die "Could not fork";
    }
    elseif ( $pid > 0 ) {
        ## boss
        $processes{$pid} = 1;
    }
    else {
        #do things in child process

        ## exit for child, dont forget this
        exit;
    }
}

## when things are right to kill ;-)
foreach my $pid ( keys %processes ) {
    kill 1, $pid;
}
```

Comment: Should use `kill TERM => $pid` instead of (something equivalent to) `kill HUP => $pid`.

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful. Is there any reason you used a hash to store the processes, or is an array also acceptable?

Comment: @user1971354, Using a hash makes it easy to remove processes that have ended. Keep in mind you'll need to reap the processes after killing them, which could look like `while (%processes) { my $pid = wait(); delete $processes{$pid}; }`

Answer (score 3):

Once you understand well what's going on in the first answer (but only then!), go have a look at [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager-1.15/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) (or something similar) for real work. There are many, many small niggling details that you can get wrong while working with child processes, so using a third-party module for that can save you a lot of time.